# Apache Cordova complete tutorial

Tags: cordova, cross-platform

I need to develop a cross-platform app. If someone of you have already tried Cordova please give me a feedback, I really need a complete tutorial or clear samples.
Thank  you !

Comment: Recently I built a hybrid mobile app from scratch using Cordova that runs fine in both iOS and Android platforms. I'm in the process of writing the work in a series of articles you can start from here http://prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2015/8/how_to_create_an_awesome_hybrid_mobile_app

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check this tutorial, it covers quite well the subject :

- http://coenraets.org/blog/cordova-phonegap-3-tutorial/
- [How to install/run PhoneGap on Ubuntu, Step by step guide](http://dasunhegoda.com/installrun-phonegap-ubuntu/797/)